# Selecting web framework for an installable project

Tags: web-applications, installation, cross-platform, web-frameworks

I am currently in the process of evaluating different web application frameworks for a client.  The problem we are facing is that the customer requires the web app to be delivered as an installable package for all the major OSs (Windows, MacOS X and misc linux flavors) which will be set up by their users which may not be too technically advanced.
Since the project has to be cross-platform, I guess we can rule out ASP.NET and they do not seem too fond of Java for some reason.  So what does that leave us?

To elaborate a bit on the app we intend to write, it will be a basic UI on top of an existing server app which we can access through a SOAP API.  The server has a slightly different view of the world than we want to present to the user, so the web-backend will have to do some data shuffling and caching but the web UI will probably be a simple 'select items from a list and perform actions on them' affair with some AJAX eye candy thrown in. Since we're not talking to a database directly, ORM and the ability to quickly map the database schema to view is not all that important to us, and as there will be one web server running at each customers office and the server app does all the heavy lifting, scalability is not much of an issue.  The main issue we need to get out of the way first is the "installable" requirement.  Pretty much all other variables (language, design, features etc) are secondary

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Real Studio Web Edition, which can create web applications that can be installed on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.  The web app itself it a single compiled executable so it might be easier for your clients to install.

This is a *very* new product (only released in Dec 2010 and still going through significant changes), so you should evaluate it carefully before even considering it.

But it does look like it would meet your requirements well enough.

http://www.realsoftware.com

Answer (score 0):

Any Python web library would do. bottle, CherryPy, web.py come with a built-in web server. You simply package up the 'server' using py2exe (or the Mac equivalent, Linux users may be happy with a 'run' script) and you're good to go. After the python web server has started up, it launched a browser pointing at localhost. I did exactly this with web.py many moons ago. 
Could have taken it slightly further and built a single site browser - embedded Webkit or IE, trivial to do.
(NB: Python is just an example here - you could do the same with Java/Tomcat, etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063140/is-there-an-open-source-framework-for-building-desktop-apps-that-run-in-the-brows/6065331#6065331) for more details.