# Is there an Open Source framework for building desktop apps that run in the browser?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, frameworks, desktop

I'm interested in starting an Open Source project that could be packaged as a desktop application for non-technical end users, but would run in the browser - one existing model would be [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/). I'm looking for an **existing, Open-Source framework** that would support this - *not* the UI portion, but the lower-level application framework, including:

- Data persistence (preferably via some sort of ORM)
- Desktop-based webserver (I'm assuming this would be necessary to support a browser-based UI)
- Filesystem access
- Security/sandboxing (e.g. to address the XSS/CSRF issues of running your own webserver)
- Support for basic web app elements (e.g. URL handling, templating) or for another web app framework that could handle this
- Packaging the project for one-click installation (i.e. the user should not need to have Python, node, or other technologies installed)

I'm hoping to find a framework that sets up a significant amount of this for me, the way that Django sets up web applications - not just a technology that would support writing this framework myself.

My ideal framework would be **cross-platform** and **cross-browser**, and would be written in either Python, Java, or Javascript (running on node.js or something similar). Does a framework like this exist?

Comment: [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html) addresses some of those issues. "Using Java Web Start technology, standalone Java software applications can be deployed with a single click over the network. Java Web Start ensures the most current version of the application will be deployed, as well as the correct version of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE)." However, doesn't seem very popular. Was given about as much love as Applets.

Comment: @nrabinowitz node.js coupled with couch or mongo matches all those features you just need to build the "high level abstraction" layer yourself. Your also far too vague in what you want. I'm almost tempted to say just use the power-tool that is Sharepoint ;)

Comment: @Raynos - I've considered node.js (noted in the question) - the abstraction layer/framework is exactly what I'm looking for, as this doesn't seem like an uncommon setup. Can you explain what seems vague here, so I can clarify the question? I'm confused as to how Sharepoint would possibly fit the bill, as it doesn't run on the desktop and isn't Open Source.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Sharepoint doesn't fit, it was a joke about how generic your requirements are. What I want to know is what high level sugar on top of node.js is missing?

Comment: I've edited the question - please let me know if it's still too vague. Node.js + Mongo is a technology stack, not a fully-featured framework like Django - it's the framework I'm looking for.

Comment: @nrabinowitz using express, backbone and cradle will get you far. You can easily write an installation script that creates an executable. FS & sandboxing is build into node.js itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to build a desktop app that runs in the browser using [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). Web2py requires no installation or configuration, has no dependencies, and includes a built-in web server and the SQLite RDBMS (as well as a database abstraction layer). The Windows and Mac binaries even include the Python interpreter, so no need to install Python (you can even run it off a thumb drive). You can pack your application with a web2py distribution, and your users will simply have to unzip it, click a single file to start it, and your app will launch in their browser. You can even distribute your applications as binaries, as explained [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/12#How-to-Distribute-your-Applications-as-Binaries).

The [documentation](http://web2py.com/book/) is excellent, and if you have any questions, there's a very helpful and responsive [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

If you want to start playing with it, just [download](http://web2py.com/examples/default/download) it, unzip it, and click the web2py.exe (Windows) or web2py.app (Mac) file -- that will launch the "welcome" (scaffolding) app in your browser. If there's something it's lacking that would be helpful for your use case, ask on the list -- if the change is easy and useful, it will probably get added.

Comment: Oooh, that looks very promising. I'll check it out - thanks!

Comment: I've looked around a bit, and this seems closest to what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [PyJavascriptCore](https://launchpad.net/pyjavascriptcore) and the PyGTK Webkit implementation which will let you make an application in HTML, CSS, and Javascript. For the backend you can either use Python since with PyJavascriptCore you can call Javascript functions from Python and vice versa, or you can combine with a WSGI framework like Flask to do Ajax calls to the app's local server.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this is a pretty interesting project, but I'm not sure it fits the bill. I'm hoping to run in the user's web browser, rather than opening an app-based browser window, though it might be worth considering. I'm also hoping for a framework with a bit more built-in support than "use Python" :).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/)

Comment: Pyjamas looks interesting, but as far as I can tell it doesn't deal at all with several of my key requirements - webserver, data persistence, etc. It looks like it's mostly concerned with the front-end UI, rather than back-end support. Am I wrong?